# reCaptcha configuration for Matrix Synapse

Tags: recaptcha, matrix-synapse

My configuration in `homeserver.yaml` is as follows (no quotes of any sort around the keys):

```
recaptcha_public_key: the_public_key
recaptcha_private_key: the_private_key
enable_registration_captcha: true
```

I have verified that changes in `homeserver.yaml` are taken into account.

I have also tested that the reCaptcha widget works by trying it out on the same domain (`https://testcaptcha.the_domain.com/test` for the test and `https://matrix.the_domain.com` for the actual matrix url).

My `x_forwarded` is set to `true`.

When I try to register a user using the Element client (formerly Riot) I get the following :

[image]

How can I get the reCaptcha widget to work properly ?

Answer (score 2):

Oh I just figured this out. I found this trying to solve the problem myself. It is obvious in hindsight.

Add app.element.io or whatever domain you are running the element web client from as a legitimate source of the request. The request for the recaptcha is coming from there not from your homeserver.

Comment: Thks for the explanation. Where should I add this domain though? As in which config file etc. Also I thought everything was running on my server. I have to look at the docs again! 